# Disabling angular 2 routes for external, manual entry - internal router.navigate only?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is it possible to make it so my angular 2 routes only work if they are accessed by my router.navigate internal logic so that if a user types routes manually into the url it redirects them to the main page?

Comment: I don't believe so. Check out route-guards through for protecting routes, you could probably accomplish what you're asking.

Comment: I can break my site if I type something like /success?=blabla because it is expecting data to be there that isn't and it creates a blabla object. I am using those params to retrieve callback data. Not sure real users will be doing things like this but it feels sloppy. Any suggestions?